# Is a 422 status code appropriate for unable to delete object?

Tags: http

Given a DELETE request to a resource with an id. e.g. 'DELETE /products/:id/ if the resource cannot be deleted is it appropriate to respond with a 422 Unprocessable Entity. Or should the server just respond with a 400.

Comment: Maybe `418 I'm a teapot (RFC 2324)` could work too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

422 is probably not suitable in the general case, as it is a [WebDAV specific](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918) code.

If the issue is such that a user can resolve it, `409 conflict` would be suitable. Otherwise, I think 400 is the best available response.

**The question was modified from `resource does not exist` to `resource cannot be deleted`. I have left my original answer below.**

I suggest `404: Not found` is the appropriate response here.

Alternetively, `410: Gone` is appropriate if you are able to determine that this product **did** exist, but has since been deleted.

Comment: @RB. Yeah, I saw that after posting, hence the attempted <strike> ::p Other comments remove, this will disappear soon.

Comment: You are right that 422 doesn't apply here, however the reasoning about WebDAV doesn't make a lot of sense.